# Simple solution for PDF storage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, storage

I'm trying to make a PDF storage that can be accessed by anyone who has the URL to the specific PDF file. Basically I want to be able to hand out just a URL to a person and that leads to the PDF file.
I'm looking for simple and efficient solution to this. I have 2 VPS server each running on Ubuntu.

(Each PDF file needs to be accessed by URL)

Answer (score 3):

Object storage solutions such as [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [Backblaze B2](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to serve static files. You need a server like apache2 or nginx
example vhost for apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myservername.website
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/static/
</VirtualHost>
```

and then you just need to place your PDF files into `/var/www/static` dir